# How to select the string using regex lookup?

Tags: regex

I tried to select the string using regex

```
 Test('A0','_VAL=TEST.Valu&_LMT=V007&TYPE=120')
  Test('A0','_VAL=TEST1.Valu&TYPE=121')
```

I tried Regex:  http://rubular.com/r/jU2twjGDzo
OutPut :

```
Match1: 
1._VAL=TEST.Valu

Match 2:
1. _LMT=V007

Match 3:
1. TYPE=120

Match 4:
_VAL=TEST1.Valu

Match 5:
1. TYPE=121
```

Comment: what is the pattern you want to match?

Comment: I need split using the '&'

Comment: @Charge Can't you just use a string splitting function then? Which language are you using?

Comment: C# @ctwheels...

Comment: @Charge you should do something along the lines of `string[] tokens = str.Split('&');` where `str` contains your string. Regex should only be used in cases where simple string parsing isn't possible. If you do want to use regex, however, you can use `[^&]+` to split on `&`

Comment: Could pls give the full regex@ctwheels

Comment: @Charge, the beauty is... That is the full regex ;) https://regex101.com/r/Rw3u2t/1

Comment: @Charge, I've moved the comments to an answer so that it might help others in the future as well

Comment: One doubt my input 'Test('A0','_VAL=TEST.Valu&_LMT=V007&TYPE=120')'..Not working proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the answer...(?<=,\s'|&)([^&')]+|)
link :  http://rubular.com/r/mln063rp2n

Comment: Not quite sure how this is the answer, it doesn't grab the first value. Also, what do apostraphes have to do with anything `'`? Same goes for whitespace `\s` and comma  `,`? Also, why is there an `|` at the end? That means you could yield no result, and, if that's intended, you should use `*` instead of `+`

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

Since in the comments, you specified C# as being the language you are using, you should be using `string[] tokens = str.Split('&');`. These string splitting functions are usually optimized to perform faster than regex (albeit there will likely be no difference based on the size of your strings/data).

If, however, you are set on regex, you can use the following code to do what you want.

---

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Rw3u2t/1)

```
[^&]+
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
_VAL=TEST.Valu&_LMT=V007&TYPE=120
```

#### Output

```
_VAL=TEST.Valu
_LMT=V007
TYPE=120
```

---

### Explanation

- `[^&]+` Match any character not present in the set `[^]` (in this case `&`), between one and unlimited times `+`